# Color a Google Map, Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an android app that uses google maps. now I would like to know whether there is a possibility to color a google map e.g. have a different color for roads and other shapes.

E.g have something like this http://odopod.com/contact/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you after is [Styled Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#StyledMaps).  This was [introduced](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/05/add-touch-of-style-to-your-maps.html) in the Javascript API recently, so I am pretty sure this functionality is not available a [MapView](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html) on Android. You could do this with a [Javascript based Google Map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) inside an [Android WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Flash API. Pretty sure the other APIs don't have it: http://blog.jactionscripters.com/2009/05/20/color-your-google-maps-flash-monochrome/

Comment: hm if it is so then there seems to be no possibility to do it in android. I clould paint the polygon by myself but this would be to much work on a mobile phone

Comment: The Javascript API does have this functionality (see my answer).